# escape button doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2

Something changed or is it a bug?

Today when i click ctrl+f, find something and press escape the panel is still open. Pressing escape do nothing.

In default bind i have:

```
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "hide_panel", "args": {"cancel": true},
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
```

Edit:
wow, better. I just discovered escape button doesn't work in sublime text in every case, every menu and places.

Edit2:
I restarted ST2 and nothing, restarted again and again. Now it's working. I don't have any idea what happend.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by closing `Adobe Photoshop CS4`.

Comment: I had `Photoshop CS2` open and closing it re-enabled the `ESC` button.

Comment: Has someone has an explanation why that bugs exists while photoshop(or maybe other programs) is running in the background.This happened to me aswell (I had Photoshop CS2 minimized).

Answer (score -1):

sorry for my english. I try to explain.
I had this problem too. I fix it. Just override "escape" default key bindings in user keymap file to another key, for example "f1", save file, remove your changes, and save file again.